# TikZ: Tilting a submatrix of a \matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgf}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,scopes,arrows,calc,shapes.misc,matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\bbrect}[3]{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\result{#1+1};
    \node[rectangle,draw,fit=(A-#1-\result.north west) (A-#1-#2.south east), inner sep = 0pt] (block#3) {}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \ttfamily
    \begin{scope}
            \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement = \&] {
                {0} \& {0} \& {1} \& {0} \& {1} \& {0}\\
                {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {1} \& {1} \& {1}\\
                {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {1} \& {0}\\
                {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {1}\\
                {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {1}\\
                {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0}\\
            };
    \end{scope}
    \bbrect{1}{5}{1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like to tilt the submatrix rectangle frame created by `\bbrect{1}{5}{1}` to some small degree -- with all its entries `0 1 0 1`, too. Since the matrix environment is used expressly for the purpose of *aligning* items, this seems near to impossible?

Comment: Also, why are you loading pretty much every TikZ library known to man? Including ones that are deprecated (`snakes`)? Best to keep minimal working examples, *minimal*.

Answer (score 4):

You can tilt the *frame* if you add the option `rotate=<angle>` to the `node` option of the `\bbrect` command.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgf}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,%
    snakes,fit,scopes,arrows,calc,shapes.misc,%
    shapes.arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing,
    shapes,backgrounds,decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\bbrect}[3]{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\result{#1+1};
    \node[rotate=-5,rectangle,draw,
          fit=(A-#1-\result.north west) (A-#1-#2.south east),
          inner sep = 0pt] (block#3) {}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \ttfamily
    \begin{scope}
            \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement = \&] {
                {0} \& {0} \& {1} \& {0} \& {1} \& {0}\\
                {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {1} \& {1} \& {1}\\
                {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {1} \& {0}\\
                {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {1}\\
                {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {1}\\
                {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0} \& {0}\\
            };
    \end{scope}
    \bbrect{1}{5}{1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```